# How to setup application roles in JBPM 6.2 deployed on tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat, jbpm

I have setup JBPM 6.2 on TOMCAT with H2 on tcp, for this I followed the steps from [https://apurvasingh67.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/how-to-install-jbpm6-on-tomcat7-x](https://apurvasingh67.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/how-to-install-jbpm6-on-tomcat7-x/)/

As my application is using mysql to authenticate the users. I changed the tomcat Realm and used JDBC Realm to authenticate the users from mysql db, for this I followed the steps from https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/JDBCRealm-howto.html

Now my application has some predifined roles like HR, Manager, TechLead, so I want to use those roles while logging into the jbpm-console and also through JBPM-rest Call.

Please help on how to add organization roles to jbpm roles. currently user/admin and other roles listed in workbench-policy.properties (apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps\jbpm-console\WEB-INF\classes) as working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I used is same as for Tomcat JDBC Realm with jbpm_users (username,password) and jbpm_roles(username, rolename) tables.

For every organization roles (HR, Manager, TechLead) participating in the bpm process I inserted the username and rolename in jbpm_roles tables on user registration and update.

Along with jbpm specific roles (admin, user, analyst, rest-all).

This resolved the dynamic role mapping with registered users and also rest access to jbpm API's.

Answer (score 0):

The workbench looks up the roles using the server specific JAAS mechanism. In the first link look at item number 7

> Edit TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml to include roles and users ...

Do you have the roles defined for HR, Manager, and Techlead defined there? Are they then assigned to specific users?

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for replying very late.